# Setup PyYaml with pyenv on Mac OS X; file not found: python.exe

Tags: python

I'm having trouble installing python packets using pip in a virtualenv. After some investigations, it turns out there seems to be a problem with PyYaml. I downloaded the last version and tried to build it. When using the "system" python, there is no problem. However, when I try to run the same command (python  setup.py install) after activating my virtualenv, I get the following error:

```
gcc -bundle -bundle_loader python.exe -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -    L/Users/a/.pyenv/versions/2.7.7/lib build/temp.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/ext/_yaml.o -lyaml -o     build/lib.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/_yaml.so
ld: file not found: python.exe
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I have no idea where it comes from... Any clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same issue using pyenv.  The dirty way I got it to install was using

```
CC=/path/to/virtualenv_dir/bin/python2.7 /path/to/virtualenv_dir/bin/pip install pyyaml
```

If you're using pyenv you can also use

```
CC=$(which python) pip install pyyaml
```

Comment: Could you explain why it works? It looks insane since Python doesn't compile  C code.

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in [pyenv#273](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/273#issuecomment-285038543), the problem happens after installing Python <2.7.8 on macOS.

You can fix it yourself:

```
$ export p=/Users/andrei/.pyenv/versions/2.7.6
$ sed -i -e "s#python.exe#${p}/bin/python2.7#g" "$p/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.py"
```

The example is for 2.7.6, replace the version if you need 2.7.7 etc.

If you don't use [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv), change the path to where Python is stored.